# AdMob Iphone SDK Integration

Tags: iphone, sdk, admob

I don't have any Application in the App Store. With the URL of my friend who has an application in the App store i have registered in Admob and Got the Iphone SDK.

I have integrated that SDK into my application. It was Successfully integrated but it is Displaying the "Iphone Test Web App" every time when iam Running the application.

It is not displaying the other Ads from the network.
I have guiven My UDID also in the code.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud set "test" to false to receive adds